# Auto login users in different sites

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need one authentication system for few sites. for example: sites: A,B,C. if user login in site A i need autologin him in B,C. any suggestions (with firebase or not)?

Comment: Currently Firebase Auth 3.x only supports single host origin sessions. You will need to login again in domain B and C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to login in 3 websites, one way to do this is on site A, embed an iframe of site B and site C. Then on sign in to site A with a credential, pass the credential to iframe B and C via postMessage. It is EXTREMELY IMPORTANT to verify the origin of parent page (it should be domain A) before sign-in with that credential on site B and C. Basically you will need to replicate operations in parent frame on child iframes. Also when you sign out in one site, make sure the embedded 2 iframes also signout.